# Geany switching on Numlock - how to disable

Tags: geany, numlock

I always use the number pad as a directional controller and I have disabled it system wide.

However geany is turning numlock on.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Sounds a little unusual! Have you had a look in: Edit --> Preferences --> Key Bindings --> Keyboard Shortcuts ?

Comment: @andrew.46 Nothing in keybindings and nothing in geany.conf.